# How can I access an objects methods from another class?

Tags: java, methods, constructor

Here's my code for the main class titled "Main.java":

```
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(640, 480));
            Display.setTitle("LWJGL TESTING");
            Display.create();
        }catch (LWJGLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Display.destroy();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glOrtho(0, 640, 480, 0, 1, -1);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()){
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            new KeyboardEventHandler();
            Line line1 = new Line(100, 100, 200, 200, 1);
            Line line2 = new Line(400, 0, 400, 100, 2);
            Display.update();
            Display.sync(60);
        }
        Display.destroy();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Here's my code for the KeyboardEventHandler class titled "KeyboardEventHandler.java":

```
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;


public class KeyboardEventHandler extends Main{
    public KeyboardEventHandler(){
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LEFT)){

        }
    }
}
```

and here's my class titled "Line.java":

```
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;
import org.lwjgl.*;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

public class Line {
    int id;
    public Line(int startx, int starty, int endx, int endy, int startingid){
        glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
            glVertex2i(startx, starty);
            glVertex2i(endx, endy);
        glEnd();
        id = startingid;
    }
    public int getLineId(){
        return id;
    }
}
```

How can I access the method getLineId() for the line "line1" from the KeyboardEventHandler class, I am fairly new to Java so I'm sorry if this is an obvious answer.

Comment: Alex Coleman is right, you should research more before asking because this is something that must have had been covered in Chapter 1 or 2 of any basic programming book. Also you should not start with LWJGl if you don't even know basic Java...don't rush ahead, it'll only slow you down in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass line into the KeyboardEventHandler constructor.

```
//New KeyboardEventHandler
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;

public class KeyboardEventHandler extends Main{
    public KeyboardEventHandler(Line passedLine /* Passing the Line object*/){
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LEFT)){
            int lineID = passedLine.getLineId();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your main class

```
/*Section from Main class*/
while (!Display.isCloseRequested()){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Line line1 = new Line(100, 100, 200, 200, 1);
    //Pass line into keyboard event handler\\
    new KeyboardEventHandler(line1);
    Line line2 = new Line(400, 0, 400, 100, 2);
    //Pass line into keyboard event handler\\
    new KeyboardEventHandler(line2);
    Display.update();
    Display.sync(60);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To invoke the method, simply use a `.` to denote a field or method (getLineId) inside of an instance (line1 or line2). To give it to the other class, pass one of your Line instances into the constructor. For you, this would be:

```
    public class KeyboardEventHandler extends Main{
        public KeyboardEventHandler(Line line){
            if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LEFT)){
                int line1Id = line1.getLineId();
            }
        }
    }
```

And in your call to it, just do `new KeyboardEventHandler(myLine);`

This code structure has some issues too, I don't see the point of even using another class there to only do one minor thing.

Also, if you don't know this, I suggest you read up more before coming onto here. This site is for asking questions that have **already been researched**, and no solutions found. This clearly has not been researched at all.

Comment: "I don't see the point of even using another class there to only do one minor thing."?? To prevent duplication?